# Array/List of class names

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to do something like:

```
ArrayList<Class> _fragments = new ArrayList<Class>{ FirstFragmentClass.class, SecondFragmentClass.class, .... }
return new _fragments.get(iterator);
//foreach(_fragments){ ... }
```

P.S. I'm writing against Android API and, if I'm not mistaken, there're slight differencies between reflection in plain java and android.

Thanks.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to do here. What are you going to do with your classes?

Comment: return new _fragments.get(iterator); I want to new an object from the classname, which I get from the list/array.

Comment: When you do `return` you're returning from a method. What do you want as *return type* of this method?

Comment: Object or any Interface that those classes share. How does it help ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, using the [`Class.newInstance()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance%28%29) method. This method invokes the no-arg constructor. Make sure your classes all have one.

```
List<Class<?>> classes = Arrays.asList(FirstFragmentClass.class, SecondFragmentClass.class);
for (Class<?> clazz : classes) {
    Object instance = clazz.newInstance();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

time ago I use something like that:

```
Hashtable<IdItem, Class<?>> activitiesToLaunch = null;
activitiesToLaunch = new Hashtable<IdItem, Class<?>>();
activitiesToLaunch.put(new IdItem(idReceivedInPush), classOfScreenToLaunch);
```

You can change the Hastable for a Vector or something like that and make your functionality.

Hope to help :)